# passing local variables in Node.js with ejs -Files

Tags: node.js

I want to make a Test-Projekt in Node.js.

I have an index.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Meine Node.js-Testanwendung</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Willkommen auf dem Mars!</h1>
    <%- include("locvar.ejs"); %>
    <%- include("result.ejs"); %>
  </body>
</html>
```

the localvar.ejs

```
<%
  var var1 = "Mars";
  var var2 = "Hallo";
%>
```

the result.ejs

```
<%- include("locvar.ejs"); %>
<h2>Original Variablen:</h2>
<p>var1: <%= var1 %></p>
<p>var2: <%= var2 %></p>

<%- include ("change.ejs"); %>
<h2>Change Variablen:</h2>
<p>var1: <%= var1 %></p>
<p>var2: <%= var2 %></p>

<%
  var1 = "Houston";
  var2 = "Problem";
%>

<h2>Geänderte Variablen:</h2>
<p>var1: <%= var1 %></p>
<p>var2: <%= var2 %></p>
```

and the change.ejs

```
<%
  var1 = "Hallo";
  var2 = "Mond";
%>
```

and here is the server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const ejs = require('ejs');

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index.ejs');
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server started on port 3000');
});
```

How I can passing local variables?

First the result.ejs should show at first the data from locvar.ejs, then from change.ejs and at the end from result.

Answer (score 0):

And here is the solution:

server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const path = require('path');
const local = require('./locvar');

const app = express();

// Middleware to initialize the session object
app.use(session({
  secret: 'my-secret-key',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));

// Middleware to expose the config object to all routes
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.local = local;
  next();
});

// Set up the view engine
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// Route to render the index.ejs template
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index');
});

// Start the server
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server started on port 3000');
});
```

locvar.js <- nicht .ejs

```
<%
  var var1 = "Mars";
  var var2 = "Hallo";
%>
```

index.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
  <head>
    <title>Meine Node.js-Testanwendung</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Willkommen auf dem Mars!</h1>
    <%- include("result.ejs"); %>
  </body>
</html>
```

result.ejs

```
<h1>Original Variablen </h1>
<p>var1: <%= local.var1 %></p>
<p>var2: <%= local.var2 %></p>

<%- include("change.ejs"); %>
<h1>Change Variablen </h1>
<p>var1: <%= local.var1 %></p>
<p>var2: <%= local.var2 %></p>

<%
  local.var1 = "Housten";
  local.var2 = "Problem";
%>
<h1>Result Variablen </h1>
<p>var1: <%= local.var1 %></p>
<p>var2: <%= local.var2 %></p>e
```

change.ejs

```
<%
  local.var1 = "Hallo";
  local.var2 = "Mond";
%>
```

Important is here that we have the middelware-route in the server.js